# Move uploaded files to different directory depends on file extenions

Tags: php, file-upload

Sorry I'm not the best with php. My questions is.
Can i upload files depends on their extensions like here in php.
Can any body help me please

```
string path = System.String.Empty;
 if (image == true)
     path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/Images") + e.FileName;
 else
     path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/Docs") + e.FileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

pathinfo function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) can help you to extract file extension

Also https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php to deal with uplaoded files